# why there is no option to run as TestNG after closing eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

why there is no option to run as TestNG after closing eclipse? I had that option before.

How can I get run as TestNG option in eclipse for selenium webdriver?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It's very difficult for me to understand your question.  Anyway, maybe you can try to run testng on the cmd line.

Comment: Please make sure you have the testng plugin installed in eclipse.Go to About eclipse-->Installation details and verify whether TestNg is visible as a part of Installed Softwares, If not, then go to Install new software option in eclipse and add the following link http://beust.com/eclipse. Click on finish to complete the installation

Comment: I had to install testng plugin again... Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you need to re-install the TestNG Eclipse plugin. It may be worth making sure that you are loading up the same workspace as well.

FYI, I think that you should remove the [selenium-webdriver] tag, as this is only tangentially related to selenium or webdriver.

Comment: Yea i re-installed TestNG plugin.. Thanks!